# Domaine - Can you expand into an opponent's domain if your domain and his have no knights?

Tags: domaine

According to the Domaine rules, you must have more knights in your domain than your opponent's domain to expand into his.

If both domains have no knights, does it mean that neither domain can expand into each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, that is correct.

If your domain has no knights it can only expand into territory that is not part of any domain.  In this case you should get some knights into your domain and take advantage of your neighbor before he does the same to you!